# Symfony Reflection for TestClasses returns 'PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase' not found at vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

So, I'm trying to extract details via reflection from all Test classes in my Symfony Application.

When I run `bin/phpunit`, all tests pass. So, with this, I understand that `phpunit` is installed correctly, `composer` is set up correctly, etc..

So, when I want to create a class via Reflection, either with native PHP code or with `Symfony's PropertyInfoExtractor`, it throws this message:

```
[2019-07-27 08:30:50] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Error: Class 'PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase' not found at /Users/user/Documents/project/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:24)"} []
```

So, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Can you give more context, e.g. a code snippet that causes the error and how it was executed? Does this problem occur inside your tests or in your src/?

Comment: When you use Symfony's PhpunitBridge phpunit will not be installed alongside your other dependencies. Instead it is kept completely separate from your project. This is to ensure that there are no side effects and that dependencies required by phpunit will not conflict with any of your application dependencies. This could be the cause of your issue, the class you are trying to get is probably not autoloaded, but this is just a guess.